Equation Curve generation not matching current view / UCS
I set up a part with parameters as follows:

I then proceed to start start a sketch on the XZ plane.  I adjusted the view so the orientation of X would be positive to the right and Z would be positive up.
I then proceeded to enter a parabolic equation representing the vertical curve in road design:
Y= (G2-G1)/(2*LVC)*x^2+G1*x+BCVE

x-min = 0
x-max = LVC

The equation displays the right shape but in the wrong direction.  I need LVC to be in the positive X direction.

What I have tried.

Setting the current view to front
Changing the default orientation in setting
Mirroring the result about the Z axis.  (problem is I do not know how to erase the original as the mirrored image deletes with the original).
Selecting the underside (opposite face) of the XZ plane when starting the sketch.

QUESTION
How to create an equation curve that follows the the axis of the current view?
